# Get url in templatetags in Django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have function to_date in view.py, which passing date from url  http://www.example.com/2014/05/03/;
to_date generates a link to the requested url and generates a link tomorrow_date tomorrow.  Also, there is some logic that handling date from url:

```
def to_date(request, year, month, day):

    day = int(day)
    month = int(month)
    year = int(year)

    current_date = '{year}{month}{day}'.format(year=year,
                                               month=date.month,
                                               day=date.day)

    next_date = datetime(year, month, day) + timedelta(days=1)
    tomorrow_date = '{year}{month}{day}'.format(year=next_date.year,
                                                month=next_date.month,
                                                day=next_date.day)

    # Any logic:
    # ...do_something


    template = loader.get_template('content.html')
    context = RequestContext(request, {
        'current_date': current_date,
        'tomorrow_date': tomorrow_date,
        #'do_something': do_something,
    })

    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

UPD:

I have content.html with tags:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div class='content'>
    {{ do_something }}
</div>
<ul class='menu'>
    <li><a href='{{ current_date }}'>Current date</a></li>
    <li><a href='{{ tomorrow_date }}'>Tomorrow date</a></li>
</ul>
{% endblock %}
```

I moved links to menu.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block menu %}
<ul class='menu'>
    <li><a href='{{ current_date }}'>Current date</a></li>
    <li><a href='{{ tomorrow_date }}'>Tomorrow date</a></li>
</ul>
{% endblock %}
```

To move links to menu.html is needed, they should separate links 
from content.html. Function views.to_date takes data from the url (it's arbitrary)and generates data and links and gives template content.html, when I removed links to menu.html, I did't know how to create templatetag so he took the data from url like function to_date (request, year, month, day) and gave to response menu.html.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by menu.html and content.html?

Comment: @Alex content.html contain links and content, all were generated by a single function need to split the function that gives the content and that gives menu.html